# Test Api 404 on multiple requests

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to test all the routes on my api but only the first request gets 200, all the other following requests get 404. But if I run any test individually using (phpunit --filter test_something) it works.

```
<?php

class ProgramTest extends TestCase {

/** @test */
public function it_returns_index() {
    $this->get('api/v1/test')
         ->assertReturnOk(['limit' => 10]);
}

/** @test */
public function it_returns_show() {
    $this->get('api/v1/test/12')
         ->seeJson(['id' => 12]);
}
}
```

getting error as

```
PHPUnit 4.8.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.F
Time: 2.33 seconds, Memory: 20.25Mb
There was 1 failure:
1) ProgramTest::it_returns_show
Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the problem in Routes.php I think. I have seen a similar question that has been answered in the below link. Hope this would solve you. The Route modification that was done is as per the below link

```
$phpunit = simplexml_load_file('phpunit.xml');

foreach (File::allFiles(__DIR__ . '/Routes') as $partial) {
if ($phpunit->php->xpath('env[@name="APP_ENV"]')[0]['value'] == 'testing') {
    require $partial->getPathname();
} else {
    require_once $partial->getPathname();
}
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/test-api-404-on-multiple-requests